# Getting feed items from Google reader belonging to a subscription whose URL contains a question mark (query string)?

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, google-reader

I am trying to get feeds belonging to a particular subscription in Google reader using the usual GET request to https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/{FEED URL}?ot=1253052000&r=n&xt=user/-/state/com.google/read&n=20&ck=1255646178892&client=myApplication.

Everything seems to be fine except when the URL contains a query string such as http://www.aljazeera.com/Services/Rss/?PostingId=2007731105943979989. I get errors and when I check the response, I am told that "The requested URL '/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/{SUBSCRIPTION URL MINUS QUERY STRING}' was not found on this server". I know that somehow the query strings of the subscription URL and the request URL are getting mixed up. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to Url Encode the Feed Url. There's an encoding in urls that converts any special character into a sequence of characters that won't interfere with query operations. You see this a lot when people use spaces, your browser will put `%20`.

In C# The place I know to find UrlEncode is [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)

### Update

Yes the [WebUtility.UrlEncode(string url)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx) method will work too.

The idea is that when you have text you want to insert into an url, but you don't want it to affect the behavior/parsing of your url, you encode the text you want to insert. Obviously inserting one url into another will likely cause undesireable results, so the url you're putting into the {FEED URL} is what needs encoding.

Example:

```
// The ?, &, and :// will likely cause some interesting parsing by
// the target webserver.
var feedUrl = "http://site.com/url?a=1&b=2";

var serviceUrl = "https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/{0}?ot=1253052000&r=n&xt=user/-state/com.google/read&n=20&ck=1255646178892&client=myApplication";

var resultUrl = string.Format(serviceUrl, WebUtility.UrlEncode(feedUrl));
```

Resulting url would be:

```
https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Furl%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2?ot=1253052000&r=n&xt=user/-state/com.google/read&n=20&ck=1255646178892&client=myApplication
```

Which should work for you just fine.

Comment: Thanks. On WinRT, its WebUtility.UrlEncode(string url). But do I have to encode the entire url for the request or only the url of the subscription?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm!